# Команда, которая ищет файлы в текущем каталоге и удаляет их

Tags: bash, find

Нужна команда, которая делает поиск в текущем каталоге и его подкаталогах, найти все файлы, которые либо заканчиваются на "~", либо и начинаются и заканчиваются на "#".

Команда должна показать и удалить все найденные файлы.

Допускается только одна команда без ’;’,  ’&&’ и других трюков.

Нужно сделать через команду find, флаги просто правильно расставить как я понял

Comment: Вот Вы хотите чтобы люди потратили время и бесплатно за Вас написали код по ТЗ. При этом сами не хотите потратить минуту на то, чтобы перевести задание и рассказать с какой именно частью у Вас возникли проблемы при выполнении. Нельзя так с людьми.

Comment: У меня плохо с английским, поэтому боялся не корректно донести инфу до людей. Подразумевал что профессионалам в этой области не затруднит понять ТЗ на англ. Прошу прощения раз ошибся. 
Суть ТЗ просто в команде, которая делает поиск в текущем каталоге и его подкаталогах, находит все файлы заканчивающиеся на "~" и "#" и начинающиеся с "#", показывает их а потом удаляет

Comment: Не затруднит, но лучше задавать конкретный вопрос, а не выкладывать задание. Еще вопрос: при чем здесь git? Я же правильно понимаю, что задание нужно выполнить на bash? Есть какие-то еще условия?

Comment: @default Там далее требуется работа с гит, но я решил убрать ту часть из этого вопроса, чтоб получить ответ хотя бы на этот вопрос, и дальше уже продвинуться. Забыл убрать, сейчас поправил. Больше условий нет.

Answer (score 2):

Настраиваем команду [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html):

- ищем файлы: `-type f`;
- с именами, заканчивающимися на ~ или начинающимися и заканчивающимися на #: `\( -name "*~" -o -name "#*#" \)`
- выводим имена файлов: `-print`
- удаляем файлы: `-delete`

Получаем команду:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*~" -o -name "#*#" \) -print -delete
```

Comment: Думается мне цикл можно исключить`find . -regexp '[~]\{0,1\}#*' -printf '%p\n' -delete`, в таком виде должно сработать, но утверждать не буду)

Comment: @PotroNik Да, можно одной командой. Спасибо.